# KeyPress Event waits for MousePress Event qt

Tags: qt

So I'm writing a qtwidget that requires keyboard and mouse input by overriding the respective functions. However the keypress event doesnt happen until a mousepress event occurs.  I've played around with the focus a bit and that doesnt seem to help.  I feel like I'm missing something regarding how qt processes events.  Can any of you fill me in. Thank you

Here are what i think are the relevant bits of code. Let me know if you need more

```
MeshTest::MeshTest(QWidget *parent) :
  QGLWidget(parent)
{
setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
/* Other stuff */

}
void MeshTest::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {

    /* Some math/ray casting here */
    hasHit = MeshTest::findIntersections(x,y,z,dirx,diry,dirz);


  }
}
void MeshTest::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
  if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
      /* Some ray casting stuff here */
  }

  if(hasHit)
    updateGL();
}

void MeshTest::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event){
  printf("Key Pressed\n"); //Just for debugging this particular bug
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could post some code? Sounds like the MainWindow class (if you have one..?) is taking the key events and the the reason the widget only takes them after a mouse event is because it has focus then. You might want to try setFocusPolicy(Qt:: StrongPolicy) for the widget, see if that works.

Comment: Right I added that line to the constructor of the widget but it did not correct the problem. I'll get some code up in a few

Comment: Also added NoFocus to the main window but still got the same problem

Comment: have you tried calling `setFocus` to give the widget the focus in the first place?

Comment: So I added that to the constructor of the widget. Is that correct? If so the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i fixed this a few days ago.  The solution is to overide QWidget::event(QEvent *event)
and do all event handling in the function itself